# Google Adwords SOAP Request

Tags: google-ads-api

I am using the Java Adwords API. Is there a way that I can see what the SOAP request looks like that is being sent when I create an AdGroup (mutate)?

Comment: How have you implemented this? I need help too

Answer (score 0):

You can view the SOAP XML by [enabling logging](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-java/source/browse/examples/adwords_axis/src/main/resources/log4j.properties). The default `soapXmlLogger` is just configured to log errors, but you can change it from `WARN` to `INFO` if you want to see everything; for example:

```
log4j.category.com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.client.AdWordsServiceClient.soapXmlLogger=INFO, SOAP_LOG, CONSOLE
```

Comment: Pentaho Data integration don't offer connectivity step to Adwords, only has analytics step, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

with your user object - call -

$user->LogAll();

by default this will write to a file called soap_xml.log - you might need to create it or adjust the permissions to make sure it is writable by apache - but you should be able to see all the soap requests there.

Answer (score 0):

Using **log4j.xml**, the following appender will remove soap request/response logs

```
<logger name="com.google.api.ads.adwords.lib.client.AdWordsServiceClient.soapXmlLogger"  additivity="false">
    <level value="error"/>
    <appender-ref ref="<your-appender>"/>
</logger>
```